# Where do I put the where clause in this query to filter results?

Tags: mysql, sql, select, join, where-clause

I'm trying to insert a where clause in a query to only choose certain rows.

This is the query:

```
SELECT m.MapName, SEC_TO_TIME(TRUNCATE(t.Time,3)) AS Time, p.User
FROM times t INNER JOIN
     maps m INNER JOIN
     players p
     ON t.MapID = m.MapID INNER JOIN
     (SELECT t.MapId, MIN(t.time) as time
      FROM times t
      GROUP BY t.MapId
     ) tmin
     ON tmin.MapId = t.MapId and tmin.time = t.time and p.PlayerID = t.PlayerID;
```

What I'd like to do is add a WHERE clause too only select times that have `style` = 0 and `type` = 0 in the table `times`.

Currently running that query returns all times in the form of:

```
MapName:       Time:            PlayerID:
map_name       00:00:09.440     player_name1
map_name2      xx:xx:xx:xxx     player_name2
map_name3      xx:xx:xx:xxx     player_name3
```

If this helps, the layout of the table `times` is like this:

```
MapID:      Type:      Style:      Time:
1           0          0           214.235
2           1          0           12.325
3           0          1           321.333
```

What I want to do is the same query above, but only choosing the times that have a `type` and `style` of 0.

Comment: It's unclear whether you want to get the minimum time for each player that satisfies the specified conditions, or if you want the minimum time (out of all times) for a player, and then restrict the rows returned to only those minimum times that meet the specified criteria. Where you put the predicate really depends on the resultset you want to return.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT m.MapName, SEC_TO_TIME(TRUNCATE(t.Time,3)) AS Time, p.User
FROM times t 
INNER JOIN maps m ON t.MapID = m.MapID 
INNER JOIN players p ON p.PlayerID = t.PlayerID
INNER JOIN (SELECT t.MapId, MIN(t.time) as time
            FROM times t
            WHERE t.style = 0 and t.type = 0 
            GROUP BY t.MapId
          ) tmin ON tmin.MapId = t.MapId and tmin.time = t.time;
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
...           ON     tmin.MapId = t.MapId
                 and tmin.time = t.time
                 and p.PlayerID = t.PlayerID
 WHERE times.type =0 and times.style = 0;
```